# How do I construct a Complex Django Query where sometimes the conditions are ALL

Tags: django, django-views

Let's say I have three Choicefields and I know their values in my view.  For example:

```
    fpriority = filtform["priority"].value()
    fstatus = filtform["status"].value()
    fassigned = filtform["assigned"].value()
```

The values of each will be an integer (for example, 1-3) that relates to the appropriate column in the Table. So my first thoughts on Query is this:

```
        tasks = Task.objects.filter(Q(priority=fpriority) & Q(
            status=fstatus) & Q(assigned_to=fassigned))
```

The problem I have though, is that I also want a choice for all. So lets say I include zero (0) in each ChoiceField to signify ALL

So now each of the above Q conditions must include the possibility that the variable is 0 and therefore means ALL for that part of the condition.

Any thoughts on a clean way to do this?

EDIT: The comments below have been very constructive but I am not quite there yet.  The suggestion assumes that if one parameter is zero, than all are zero - which is not the case. I've learned a lot about Q but more work to be done.  I have made my multi filter system work now, but it is an awful kludge.  So I would like to see a more elegant solution if possible.  Here is code that does the job:

```
    fpriority = filtform["priority"].value()
    fstatus = int(filtform["status"].value())
    fassigned = int(filtform["assigned"].value())

    tasklist = get_object_or_404(TaskList, owner=request.user)
    if tasklist:

        if fpriority == "0":  # all priorities
            step1 = Task.objects.all()
        else:
            step1 = Task.objects.filter(priority=fpriority)

        if fstatus == 0:  # all status's
            step2 = step1
        else:
            step2 = step1.filter(status_id=fstatus)

        if fassigned == 0:  # all assigned people
            step3 = step2
        else:
            step3 = step2.filter(assigned_to_id=fassigned)

        tasks = step3
        # tasks = Task.objects.filter(Q(priority=fpriority) & Q(
        #    status=fstatus) & Q(assigned_to=fassigned))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```py
q = Q()  # or initialize with filter conditions that should apply in any case

if not (fpriority == 0 and fstatus == 0 and fassigned == 0):
    q = q & Q(priority=fpriority) & Q(status=fstatus) & Q(assigned_to=fassigned)

tasks = Task.objects.filter(q)
```

or similar conditions on the values of your filters.

EDIT: you can also set single filters to 'all':

```
q = Q()

if fpriority > 0:
    q &= Q(priority=fpriority)

if fstatus > 0:
    q &= Q(status=fstatus)

if fassigned  > 0:
    q &= Q(assigned_to=fassigned)

tasks = Task.objects.filter(q)
```

Each filter becomes effective only it the filter value is > 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help thus far.  You have helped me learn more about using Q in queries.  I have edited my original post above because your solution does not quite meet my needs.  I have tried to express them more clearly by posting some ugly code that actually works!

Comment: I have edited my answer to show a solution that uses single filters.